# Is it possible that Daario Naharis and Euron Greyjoy are the same person?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

There is a [reddit thread](http://www.reddit.com/r/asoiaf/comments/253zbx/) which argues that Daario = Euron; it provides a lot amount of evidence which, collectively, is pretty compelling.

Is there any *direct* evidence in the novels to support this theory, apart from the mostly circumstantial and/or coincidental evidence listed in the thread? Alternatively, is there anything in the novels that definitively rules out the possibility that they are the same person (e.g. they were in two different places at once or some other contradictions?)

To summarize the Reddit thread, in brief, the evidence in support of the theory is:

- GRRM has said there is "something more" to Daario Naharis.
- Dario and Euron look similar
- The periods where each character is 'on-screen' line up with periods where the other character's whereabouts are unknown.
- There is a significant gap between sighting of each character, long enough to travel back and forth.
- Bits of evidence linking Euron to Dany and Daario to Dany that make them seem like the same person.

Comment: For those of us who don't know the theory it'd be great if you could give some of the reasons behind this logic in your question rather than referring people to another site?

Comment: I voted to close the question. Maybe you should ask "What are the evidence that Daario and Euron are the same person" or something like this, but "is XXX theory true ?" are not proper questions to ask, from what I've understood so far on this site. If you do modify your question to "what are the evidence..." then your link satisfies quite a bit as an answer, doesn't it ?

Comment: As an example: Are there any compelling reasons to assume that Tywin and Jeor Mormont was not the same person? It is not a good way to ask a question. I doubt very much that it is possible to both lead a kingdom and a mercenary company half a world apart without anyone noticing, or losing one of the two. Besides, the much more compelling theory is that Euron has captured the Warlock Pyat Pree and has enslaved him, and he is how Euron knew of Dany, and of the horn to capture her dragons.

Comment: As trivia: I've also heard a theory that Daario is very similar to the features Jaqen H'Ghar assumed after Harrenhal, and the alchemist in the prologue of AFFC, down to the gold tooth. Along with the testimony of Melisandre, which states that a glamour is item-based and person-based, "a lock of hair, a bag of fingerbones, a pair of boots", that makes it interesting to speculate that Jaqen "borrowed" Daario's appearance.

Comment: The whole "`there's more to Daario`" can be referring to his sword hilts with the naked women on the pommels, he seems to often run his fingers over them and it gets Dany going; some believe this is some sorcery which is bewitching Dany...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The biggest problem with this theory is getting the timeline to work. The reddit thread you link says that "It's implied that Euron's using quarthian warlock magick while sailing, so anything makes sense chronologically." Yeeeah, citation needed. Euron did intend capture Qaathan warlocks, but there's never any implication they can control the wind to make ships move quickly. If they could, obviously he wouldn't have been able to capture their ship.

The Iron Islands and Meereen are very, very far away, and ships travel slowly. It took three and a half days for Stannis' fleet to get from Dragonstone to King's Landing, and they're practically right next to each other. Even when Melisandre uses her fire magic to summon favorable winds, it take Stannis weeks to reach the Wall.

Setting aside whether or not travel over that distance is possible, communication is virtually impossible. It takes months for Dany to learn that King Robert is dead. But in *A Dance With Dragons*, Dany recalls Daario from his mission with the Lamb Men, and he returns fairly promptly. Even IF Euron was capable of moving so quickly across an entire continent (doubtful), there's no way he'd be able to receive the message in the Shield Islands AND move so quickly across an entire continent.

[image: .]

The small little red line is Stannis' trip to King's Landing, which took half a week. The big yellow line is Euron/Daario's supposed commute. A more dedicated man than I created a [pretty comprehensive ASOIAF timeline](http://asoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/topic/84563-most-precise-asoiaf-timeline-in-existence/), which estimates that it took months for Victarion to cross the shorter distance between Meereen and the Shield Islands. Magic can only do so much.

Basically, the only way to make the theory work is assume there is lots and lots of magic involved, glass candles, glamours or face changing, some hitherto unknown Qartheen magic. It's so much easier to say that two characters who have nothing to do with each other are, in fact, two characters with nothing to do with each other.

Comment: Wow, that timeline is incredible. And I think your answer is the best counterargument to D=E. Thanks.

Comment: Good answer! +1 for including the lines.

Comment: A Game of Thrones conspiracy theory was closed because it was              "primarily opinion-based" Wow. That's rich.

Answer (score 2):

Surprisingly there are some [compelling arguments](http://www.reddit.com/r/asoiaf/comments/253zbx/is_daario_reallyspoilers_adwd/chdthg3) for this theory, but no hard evidence at this time. We will have to wait for the upcoming shows/books to see how it plays out.

---

That said, one strike against the theory from canon sources (the books themselves) is their eyes:

- Daario has [two blue eyes](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Daario_Naharis) as noted by Dany.
- Alternatively, Euron has a pair of mismatched eyes. [According to Theon](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Euron_Greyjoy), Euron's patch conceals a "black eye shining with malice". His right eye is as blue as summer sky and is regarded as his "smiling eye".

Then again, Theon's quote is from a sample chapter of TWOW, so maybe it is subject to change?